# Is this safe? (PHP download script)

Tags: php, security, download

I have a quick question about how safe this is to do. I have written a php force download script and the part that actually serves the file should look pretty familiar:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize("user_files/".$temp_actual));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename."\"");
readfile("user_files/".$temp_actual);
```

`$filename` is the filename they see and `$temp_actual` is the REAL filename on my server. Obviously there is a mountain of code above this to prevent bad things happening but basically, users should be able to download any content they have uploaded. if they upload a .php file, I really don't want it running on the server, i want it delivered to them via force downoad (and they DO need to be able to upload *any* file type).

It works as intended, with all file extensions being force downloaded, but I just want to make absolutely certain that they can't run any php or html files on my server.

**Additional info**

`user_files` is in the website root however is .htaccess "deny from all"
every file in the `user_files` directory is appended .file instead of the original extension the original extension is replaced when the user downloads their file (maybe a bit over the top).

Comment: Your question is in regards to all of the preceding code which you say "mountain of code above this to prevent bad things"

Comment: Don’t use *application/force-download*; use *application/octet-stream* instead.

Comment: So where are these variables coming from???  Do you understand what input validation is?

Comment: lol @Rook if I posted the whole code you woud be reading for an hour... please read comments to "aaz" below - perhaps you can help. I just want to know that the user cannot tell my server to **display** the php file rather than download it. I dont want the file parsed by php atall. Like i said, works good just now, but there might be a trick i dunno about.

Comment: @Grant  cool well you haven't given anyone enough information to tell you if this is safe.  I'll just assume its 100% secure.  Have a nice day.

Comment: @Grant - Maybe edit the question to make it clear that $temp_actual is just a numeric key + ".file" and that the only place $filename from the user is going to is a database via a parametrized query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the answer is:

it seems pretty safe to do this. For all you guys saying about input filtration etc.. let me give you a quick lowdown:

Listen guys, obviously there is more checking involved so please dont reply with a user could upload xx.xx and overwrite your xx or download xx from /../../../../ although I do appreciate your help I should have re-worked the question a little. Assume the uploads and downloads are air tight.

example filename evil.php

- an upload script takes the users file
  strips anything that is not:
  a-zA-Z0-9,!-_
- then removes the extension, stores it and the real name in a database #(and the new filename)
- the file is renamed lets say 12345.file and stored in user_files
- user_files has a CHMOD of 700 and a .htaccess reading deny from all
- when the user wants to get their file, a script accesses the database and gets the real filename, the old filename and the extension, it tells the users browser the name of the file is oldfilename.extension (evil.php) however it is still on the filesystem as 12345.file. It then sets headers for a download and uses readfile() to read the contents to the browser.

To check users can't get my server to PARSE php, I commented out the headers that open the save file download box and just used readfile(). the result was that the php was dumped to the page, but **NOT PARSED**. Further testing with eval() showed that it is not parsed either. Which is most helpful. =)

(and after reading up a bit the headers above should be changed from **application/force-download** to **application/octet-stream** (the correct mime type).

Thanks everyone who replied for all of your help - I hope this can clear stuff up for anyone that stumbles across this question in the future!

Peace!

Answer (score 3):

Is the `user_files` folder in your website root?  If so, they could upload a php file and navigate to `http://mysite.com/user_files/somefile.php` and run the code.  Granted they would need to know the temporary name of the file, but if you haven't already, you should make sure your web server is set up not to allow pages to be served from that folder (or move it outside the document root).

Comment: Hey,It is in the website root however the folder has a .htaccess file with deny from all in it :) Thanks

Comment: The same is true for javascript and files that can trick IE6 into interpreting them as javascript (which means pretty much any file type).

Answer (score 2):

Sanitize filenames. Someone will try to upload `.htaccess` to replace yours.

Even with you replacing the extension with `.file`, someone will try to upload `.htaccess\0.txt`, which will work due to [a bug](http://bugs.php.net/39863).

Someone will try `.\301\250taccess` (invalid UTF-8 sequence which might decode to `h`).

Also, someone will try to download `../../../../../etc/shadow`.

If you're on Windows, someone will try `.HTACCESS` and `..\..\..\..\..\windows\system32\conf\sam`.

The `"user_file/".$temp_actual` part is important here: it prevents triggering [URL-like filenames](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php). Maybe put a comment to that effect so it's not refactored away.

To be completely sure, and if it's convenient, encode the filenames to safe characters. E.g. `strtr(base64_encode($filename), '/', '_')`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. What i'm really trying to understand is this - if i deliver a php file to them via the method above, can they set their browser to run it from my hosting instead of having it download would it display in the window?

Comment: With that bug, they could try to upload `.htaccess\0.txt` with `Allow from all`, then upload `evil.php\0.txt`, and finally access evil.php via a direct URL. I'm not sure it would work, but you could try it if you're curious.

Comment: Hey, i've got all the bugs down i basically preg replace everything apart from a-zA-Z in the origina filename, then rename their filename to say 12345.file (stored in user_files on the filesystem) , store the cleaned filename and extension in a database. when it comes time to get it again, i grab the 12345.file from user_files, change its name (at the headers, not file system) append the original extension &send them the download box... user_fies has .htaccess deny from all and CHMOD 700... can the user force the server to process a php script that was supposed to be downoaded? Thanks again :)

Comment: Ah, I see! In that case - probably not.

Comment: @aaz yeah I'm really surprised Zend patched the null byte poising attacks. Hackers have been using that route to attack PHP for more than a decade.

Comment: @Rook Not in trunk they haven't. Maybe it'll be back for PHP 6.

Comment: @aaz Huh,  it should be noted that you can use `addslashes()` to escape the null.

Comment: @Rook Yes (though that would be bad on Windows). You could URL-encode too, that's probably the most portable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered changing (appending) the file extension on upload?
Say `myFile.php` becomes `myFile.php.txt`?

You could still display the files (for downloading purposes) as .php by using something like substr(), but having the .txt extension would render them useless for actually running on the server - regardless of directory hierarchy/location.

Comment: @aaz - Nice catch, I didn't know that.

My goal is the same though. Keep it simple, and render it useless...
Even with the bug wouldn't checking for "htaccess" at upload (and disallowing that name with RegEx) prevent the problem from occurring?

Comment: Sure, and the submitter might already be doing that. But it's hard to get completely right. And you can't be overzealous, because someone might legitimately upload `nightaccess.doc` or something. But you have to protect the PHP virtual layer, the Apache virtual layer, and the OS filesystem.